# how to align absolute child's vertical position to parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the child divs (option-info) stay just below the parent div but also give them 100% width.

Now the children are centered and have 100% but aren't positioned relative to the parent div. Is there a way to give the child div absolute width but relative positioning vertically in CSS and HTML? Thanks in advance!

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="container">

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">hardware</div>
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">design</div>
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">software</div>
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">gaming</div>
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.header {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
background-color: rgb(81, 154, 226);
font-size: 2.3em;
height: 100px;
color: white;
font-family: 'saira', arial;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #2280dd;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: auto;
top: 70px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 60px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 12px 60px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 12px 60px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
z-index: 1;
line-height: 100px;
}

#container {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.option-container {
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
margin: 22px 22px 100px 22px;
}

.option-info {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
font-family: 'roboto', arial;
font-size: 1.3em;
text-align:  center;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you restructure you HTML? I think what you want would be messy (if possible) with CSS

Comment: The short answer is no, there is not a good, clean way to do this in CSS. You can use JavaScript to do it, but that is its own mess, especially without browser-difference abstraction libraries like jQuery, etc. Rethinking the design is usually the best solution in cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried restructuring the HTML and this is what I came up with, and this is exactly what I was looking for!

```
<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">hardware</div>
<div class="info-container">
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">design</div>
<div class="info-container">
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">software</div>
<div class="info-container">
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">gaming</div>
<div class="info-container">
<div class="option-info">test</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I just changed two things with the CSS:

```
.info-container {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.option-info {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
font-family: 'roboto', arial;
font-size: 1.3em;
text-align:  center;
color: black;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
margin: auto;
top: 100px;
}
```

EDIT: I appreciate the answers, but it seems I fixed my own problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? I took the `option-info` element out of the HTML and used the `:after` pseudo to insert the text in the desired (if I understood correctly) location.

```css
.header {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
background-color: rgb(81, 154, 226);
font-size: 2.3em;
height: 100px;
color: white;
font-family: 'saira', arial;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #2280dd;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: auto;
top: 70px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 60px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 12px 60px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 12px 60px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
z-index: 1;
line-height: 100px;
}

#container {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.option-container {
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
margin: 22px 22px 100px 22px;
  position: relative;
}

.option-container:after {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 0;
  content: 'test';
  bottom: -120px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-family: 'roboto', arial;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align:  center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">hardware</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">design</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">software</div>
</div>

<div class="option-container">
<div class="header">gaming</div>
</div>

</div>
```